# How can I create a new column with values assigned based on conditions from rows in two columns?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr, mutate

---

I'm a beginner in R and am trying to create a new column that will have values determined by values of rows in two columns.

My data frame looks something like this:

`df <- data.frame(subjectid = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), subj_day = c("1_1","1_1","1_1","1_2","1_2","2_1","2_1","2_1","2_2","2_2","3_1","3_1","3_1","3_2","3_2"), done_meditation = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))`

```
> df
   subjectid subj_day done_meditation
1          1      1_1               0
2          1      1_1               0
3          1      1_1               1
4          1      1_2               1
5          1      1_2               1
6          2      2_1               0
7          2      2_1               1
8          2      2_1               1
9          2      2_2               0
10         2      2_2               0
11         3      3_1               1
12         3      3_1               1
13         3      3_1               1
14         3      3_2               1
15         3      3_2               1
```

This data is from a multi-day study, and participants provided multiple responses each day.
Each row reflects a response.

The subj_day column shows the participant number and the day of the study for that participant at the time of the response reflected in that row.

The values in 'done_meditation' refer to whether the participant had completed a meditation on that day at the time of their response. If a response was provided after completing a meditation, done_meditation = 1. So, if a participant completed a meditation before any responses on that day, all their done_meditation rows for that day would = 1.

However, if they provided some responses before completing the meditation, and some after, only some of the done_meditation rows would = 1.

I need to create a column that will provide the number of meditations a participant completed across the entire study.

So, the new data frame might look like this:

```
> df
   subjectid subj_day done_meditation total_meditations
1          1      1_1               0     2
2          1      1_1               0     2
3          1      1_1               1     2
4          1      1_2               1     2
5          1      1_2               1     2
6          2      2_1               0     1
7          2      2_1               1     1
8          2      2_1               1     1
9          2      2_2               0     1
10         2      2_2               0     1
11         3      3_1               1     2
12         3      3_1               1     2
13         3      3_1               1     2
14         3      3_2               1     2
15         3      3_2               1     2
```

Because participant 2 only completed a meditation on 1 of the 2 study days, they receive a score of 1 in every row.

Because participants 1 and 3 completed a meditation on two days of the study, they receive a score of 2 in every row.

It might be useful to know that the actual study was 7 days long, so participants could have a total_meditations score of up to 7.

I have tried to write a few loops without success and have tried to use the group_by and mutate functions in dplyr but without success. I'm very new to R and have been struggling to figure this one out.

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

**UPDATE:** I think I've found a solution that works. The below seems to do the job. Still open to any new suggestions if someone has a more elegant solution :)

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(subjectid, subj_day) %>%
  summarise(meditationCount = sum(done_meditation)) %>%
  mutate(meditationCount = ifelse(meditationCount >= 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(subjectid) %>%
  summarise(total_meditations = sum(meditationCount))
 
merged.df <- merge(df,df2, by = "subjectid")
```

Comment: Try this `dplyr` option: `df %>% group_by(subjectid) %>% mutate(total_meditations = if(0 %in% done_meditation) 1 else 2)`

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help. This works for up to 2 meditations but didn't seem to work for more than 2 meditations (which I have in my actual dataset). I think I've found a solution though and will update my post with the code :)

Comment: The reason my suggested code didn't work is you'd originally only asked for two outcomes: 1 or 2 days. I'm glad I helped get you started and that you found a more scalable solution. And as per the suggestion from @Andy Baxter, feel free to answer your own question with the solution you found.

Comment: Thank you! I realised my original post had left that unclear so I edited it to hopefully make it more clear. I really appreciate it and it definitely helped me find a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good code in constructing your own answer! A few small suggestions for condensed code:

- You could use `max` to get a 1 or 0 dependend on day instead of `sum`/`ifelse`
- You can get `summarise` to drop the `subj_day` group for you using `.groups = "drop_last"` so no need for a second `group_by` call.
- Joins can be done in pipe so don't need a newly created dataframe (example below using base R pipe but `magrittr` `%>%` pipe also works)

```r
df |> 
  group_by(subjectid, subj_day) |> 
  summarise(mediated = max(done_meditation), .groups = "drop_last") |> 
  summarise(total_meditations = sum(mediated)) |> 
  left_join(df, y = _, by = "subjectid")
    # Or use `%>% left_join(df, y = ., ...)` with magrittr pipe

#>    subjectid subj_day done_meditation total_meditations
#> 1          1      1_1               0                 2
#> 2          1      1_1               0                 2
#> 3          1      1_1               1                 2
#> 4          1      1_2               1                 2
#> 5          1      1_2               1                 2
#> 6          2      2_1               0                 1
#> 7          2      2_1               1                 1
#> 8          2      2_1               1                 1
#> 9          2      2_2               0                 1
#> 10         2      2_2               0                 1
#> 11         3      3_1               1                 2
#> 12         3      3_1               1                 2
#> 13         3      3_1               1                 2
#> 14         3      3_2               1                 2
#> 15         3      3_2               1                 2
```

P.S. On SO [you are allowed to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so if you're satisfied with your own solution do post it as an answer and you can accept it to give yourself the well-deserved credit!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your own and Andy's answer, I'd like to add another suggestion:

You could use `mutate()` instead of `summarise()` if the results of `max()` are normalised with the number of responses per group (*subj_day*) `n()`. Then the `left_join()` is no longer needed:

```
df %>% mutate(total_meditations = max(done_meditation)/n(), .by = subj_day) %>%  
  mutate(total_meditations = sum(total_meditations), .by = subjectid)
```

Comment: This is a great way around that tricky problem of maxing by day and summing by subject at the same time whilst keeping the whole dataframe!